# Faded white window panes

Tags: windows

I am looking for a way to address my faded windows panes.  I can't afford $30k in replacement window expenses.  I have builder grade windows on my home which is hitting 25 years old in age.  Is there anyway to improve the look of my windows with a hack of some sort. Whats frustrating is that I appear to be the only house on my row with faded beige looking panes when others still show white panes.   Thank you for help.

Comment: Usually window panes means the glass, which is usually clear or gets foggy if the seals fail.  Do you mean the glass or the window frame/trim?

Comment: If you mean to replace the glass itself, it'll be cheaper easier and much more energy efficient to just replace the entire window units. If you're talking trim, sashes, etc. then you can probably paint, but you haven't told us what they're made of. Aluminum and vinyl don't take paint well, but wood, so long as it's not rotten loves to be painted.